# Looking for design pattern - one type of object with different sources

Tags: php, design-patterns

With CsvReader:

```
class CsvReader {
  public static function createFromString($csvString){
    /.../
    return new static($something)
  }
}
```

I'm planning to operate with csvString coming from different sources: reading file, from body of http response, etc. So im looking for design pattern for easy creation of this csvReaders objects. For now, i have ended with something like this:

```
use SplFileInfo as UploadedFile;
use CsvReader as Reader;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as HttpClient;

class CsvFactory {
  public function createFromUploadedFile(UploadedFile $uploadedFile){
    return Reader::createFromString($uploadedFile->toString());
  }

  public function createFromHttpEndpoint(HttpClient $client, $url, $options = array()){
    $response = $client->request('GET', $url, $options);

    if($response->getStatusCode() != 200){
       throw new Exception('Http Code Not Ok', $response->getStatusCode());
    }

   return Reader::createFromString($response->getBody());
 }
}
```

I feel that it could be accomplished in the better way. But how?

Comment: *return new static($something)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you need to ask yourself is what kind of groundwork do you want to have to do? Design patterns are useful tools that help you understand and/or explain decisions for organizing code in a certain way. However you are in no way required to use any particular design pattern.

The way you've built it works fine if you want to keep the code contained within this particular class. However an alternative would be to create a `toCsv` method within a `CSVable` interface. You could then attach this to classes and force them to define how they should return when requested to output in a CSV format. Then CSV class could enforce that it is only given objects that implement your `CSVable` interface.

There are many ways to accomplish this, but you should take a step back and find a pattern that fits what you're doing; not find a pattern to apply before you know what advantages and disadvantages you want. There may not even be a pattern that fits your use-case exactly.